# How to unbind scripts from dom element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script that triggers on hover and on click events on specific tag

```
$(".dropdown-button").dropdown({ 
  hover: true, // Activate on hover
});
```

Unfortunately, triggering `onclick` event is set by default.

How Can i forbid triggering script on click event? I need it to be triggered only on hover.

I need it only in this particular case for this specific tag `.dropdown-button`.

**update**

I use `materializecss` http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html

`.off()` disables `onhover` event, but not click.

Comment: You could overwrite the click event by binding to it with an empty function.

Comment: which is the library used for the dropdown

Comment: This may be what you are looking for. http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: In other words You want to trigger click event on hover is it correct

Comment: can you bind them to two different classes?

Answer (score 1):

To forbid triggering script on click event it would be good if you overwrite the click event. You can bind this click event with a empty function.

Comment: in this case both functions are triggering - empty one and dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You probably can do this

```
var hoverTimer;
var hoverDelay = 200;

$('.dropdown-button').hover(function() {
    var $target = $(this);
    // on mouse in, start a timeout
    hoverTimer = setTimeout(function() {        
        // do your stuff here
        $target.trigger('click');         
    }, hoverDelay);
}, function() {
    // on mouse out, cancel the timer
    clearTimeout(hoverTimer);
});
```